# How can we run two services with one common model DB in Django?

Tags: django

How can we run two services with one common model DB in Django?

```
I have project structures like below
A Project has Model C in its project. ( which should be public )
B Project has Model C in its project. ( which should not be public )
```

They share Model C. But when Project B needs to change Model C then we had to manually
change model script of Project A.

It created many problems.

How can we deal with this?

Should we merge two projects in two apps on one project?
Then How can we make only one app private?